# Connecting two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables in my database - vnames and vtypes
vtypes have a name field and a id field, vnames have a id field, name field and a vtypes_id field which is a foreign key connected field. It is connected with the id field in vtypes.

I have Vname and Vtype models -

**Vname**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vname extends Model
{
    public function vtype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vtype');
    }
}
```

**Vtype**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vtype extends Model
{
    public function vname() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vtype');
    }
}
```

When i delete any column in vtype table i want to delete all the vname columns associated with it.
I found a solution like this -

```
public function vtypeDestroy($id) {
    $vtype = Vtype::find($id);
    $vtype->vname()->detach();
    $vtype->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The vtype was successfully deleted');
    return redirect('/vtypes');
}
```

but when i run this function i get an error like this - `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()`

How can i fix it?

And when i want to get the name of the vtype from vname i am not able to do it. I tried like this

```
@foreach ($vnames as $vname)
    {{ $vname->vtype()->name }}
@endforeach
```

in a view

But i got an error like this -- `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

**Please guide me how to fix this two problems which i face now.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation should be as:

Vname Model

```
class Vname extends Model
{
  public function vtype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vtype', 'vtypes_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Vtype

```
class Vtype extends Model
{
    public function vname() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vname', 'vtypes_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then you can use `delete` method to delete the relations as:

```
$vtype = Vtype::find($id);
$vtype->vname()->delete();
$vtype->delete();
```

And in your view it should be as:

```
@foreach ($vnames as $vname)
    {{ $vname->vtype->name }}
@endforeach
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: when i do `$vtype->vname()->delete();` i get an error like this `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vtypes.vtypes_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from 'vtypes' where 'vtypes'.'vtypes_id' = 2 and 'vtypes'.'vtypes_id' is not null)`

Comment: Please check the updated answer. it should be `public function vname() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vname', 'vtypes_id', 'id');
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Please use...

```
$vtype->vname()->delete();
```

instead of `$vtype->vname()->detach();`... Problem solved! For the inverse of it, `vname->vtype()` you can you `dissociate()` method... which will set `vtype_id` to null in **vname** table. More explanation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Detach is used for `belongsToMany() - belongsToMany()` relation... yours is `hasMany() - belongsTo()`.

Also, instead of doing `{{ $vname->vtype()->name }}`

please do

```
@foreach ($vnames as $vname)
    {{ $vname->vtype->name }}
@endforeach
```

The reason for this is... when you put the brackets in front of the relation name, it calls a query builder... But here, what you need is the model... So `$vname->vtype` will give you **Vtype Model** while `$vname->vtype()` will give you query builder.

Comment: when i do $vtype->vname()->delete(); i get an error like this SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vtypes.vtypes_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from 'vtypes' where 'vtypes'.'vtypes_id' = 2 and 'vtypes'.'vtypes_id' is not null)

Comment: Please change your relation from `App\Vname` in `hasMany()` relation. -> `return $this->hasMany('App\Vname', 'vtypes_id', 'id');`